# Coerciveness of a function - help

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I'm trying to show that

$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = e^{x_1^2 + x_2^2} + (x_1^2 + x_2^2 + 3x_2)^{500}$$ is not [coercive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercive_function), but am struggling to see anything.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: So... it does not depend on $x_3$? That's a major clue to what's going on.

Comment: You can go to $\infty$ by increasing $x_3$ while keeping $x_1,x_2$ constant, or bounded. Notice that the value of the function depends only on $x_1,x_2$.

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH, a TRICK!
just assumed it was a typo

thank you - would not have seen that in a 10 years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick lies in fixing $x_1,x_2$ whilst taking $\|x_3\| \to \infty$ for which $f \neq \infty$